# Make the edit summary more prominent in the suggested edit review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

The review queue for suggested edits can be flawed sometimes. I recently had a suggested edit rejected, so I made [a meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317137/3684713) about it, people agreed with me and someone made almost the exact same edit. In a way the system works.

However, this system creates noise on meta and takes much longer than necessary. In my opinion, a lot of the time the problem is that reviewers don't take enough time when reviewing suggested edits. This is understandable, since there are tons of suggested edits to review on some sites and people don't have unlimited time. Also, most of the time a quick glance tells you what you need to know to make an accurate review. If you see some code blocks being removed, the edit likely wasn't warranted.

Except when it is. In that case the editor <s>probably</s> hopefully left a hint that the edit was warranted in the edit summary. Sadly edit summaries don't exactly demand a ton lot of attention in the suggested edit review queue:

[image: edit summary in review queue]

The red circle might actually improve the situation, but leave that away and the eye is drawn towards the title of the question and the red and green patches. But instead of hand-drawn red circles, I'd prefer a solution that goes more in the direction of:

[image: suggested solution]

This way, the summary demands the attention it deserves.

<s>To make it even better it could only appear this large if the editor actually typed the summary themselves and leave them as they are now when it's an auto-generated one. That way, they don't unnecessarily draw the eye in when they contain no useful information and stand out even more when they do.</s>

Apparently suggested edits must have a custom summary.

Comment: From my experience, as a user not over 2k on any site, I've never had the editor auto-generate a comment unless it was on my own post. Also from my experience browsing... Most users, at least on SO, don't put a useful edit comment, so it would _usually_ contain no useful information anyway. (e.g. "Fixed formatting" when several word changes were made, "Fixed grammar" and changes to code/formatting are made, etc.)

Comment: I *think* they *used* to be highlighted yellow...?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Not sure, I think that's in the preview, not while reviewing.

Comment: *"if the editor actually typed the summary themselves"* Auto-generated edit summaries are not possible for suggested edits. Leaving the edit summary blank on a suggested edit doesn't allow the edit to be submitted.

Comment: @Kendra: That might start a trend of rejecting edits with terrible summaries, which might not be the worst outcome.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I certainly wouldn't argue against that outcome.